# Sharepoint 2010 add,edit,delete forms replace to custome visual web parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

It`s possible in sharepoint 2010, will set up a list of custom data source and then adapt new input forms from visual web parts which will replace the existing add, edit and delete forms?

if it is possible, then how?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly? If you just want to know if you can replace the standard add, edit and delete forms, then yes. Foreach list created, an add, edit and delete form is added, which you can fully edit for specific list.

Comment: In this custom forms I want multi-dimensional data adjustment, the table with additional menus and queues

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on MSDN that describes [how to use InfoPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554886.aspx) to customise the Display, Edit and New forms for external list data (business connectivity services).

Just like in SharePoint 2007 you can change the association of the New, Edit and Display forms using SharePoint Designer in SharePoint 2010. You can create new ASPX pages, or use InfoPath forms as per the above. These ASPX pages can contain the functionality you want directly, or host visual web parts with the right permissions.

Here is an article that describes [how to change the associated forms for a list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010378258.aspx) with SharePoint Designer. I would recommend creating new pages and associating the list to those rather than trying to update the existing pages. This avoids any problems if the out of the box files are updated by a service pack / hotfix etc, and also allows you to revert to the out of the box forms if needed.